# Wordpress - add category to page permalink

Tags: wordpress, categories, permalinks

How can I add a page-category (not post) to page-permalink in wordpress?
I have this code, but it's only works with hard-coded categories. I need somothing like this '%category%/%pagename%/'.

```
     function wploop_page_permalink() {
     global $wp_rewrite;
     $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->root . 'example-category/%pagename%/';
     }
     add_action( 'init', 'wploop_page_permalink' );
```

Or maybe somothing like this (if it's only posible with hard-coded category names):

```
     if page is category_id=5
     than $wp_rewrite->root . 'category-name/%pagename%/'
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're looking for, but a few tips: rather than building your slugs manually, learn about the built-in WordPress function [add_query_arg](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/) - plus there is also the [add_rewrite_endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint)

Comment: How in ANY WAY is it unclear what he wants to do? 

He wants to add the category a page is set to to the permalink. Pages do not have categories HOWEVER they can be added with additional functions. 

I TOO would like to know how.